# Which city in the DC Universe has the highest crime rate?

Tags: dc-animated-universe, dc

While writing my comment on [@Thunderforge's question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116268/30726), I began to wonder about the other cities in the DC Universe.

[ComicVine](http://www.comicvine.com/forums/gen-discussion-1/most-crime-infested-dc-city-1669742/) did a Poll, but only 27 people participated and *Gotham City* "won" followed by *Blüdhaven*. But that is argueably just fans giving an opinion (and not very many at that).

Obviously, crime is diverse, so while Gotham may have a whole plethora of total nutjobs, the murder rate might actually be quite low, or while Superman manages to catch every bank robber in Metropolis he might have much more trouble with a serial killer, so the Metropolis murder rate could be much higher.

*Has there ever been anything official* - maybe somebody reported the newest crime statistic to President Luthor or something of that sort - *in any of the comics or supplementary material about **the** most crime ridden city in the DC Universe?*

**PS:** While this question is about the *DC Comic Universe*, mostly because it has the largest amount of source material which increases the chance for there being an answer, any other incarnation of the *DC Universe* is equally welcome. There may after all be a quote from a TV show or movie (live action or animated) or game stating that city *X* has the highest crime rate...

Comment: You said "universe", but... do you want any town or only towns/cities in America?

Comment: I'm going to guess Detroit. BAD things happen in DC Detroit.

Comment: @TylerH I actually have no idea. I thought only about the US when writing the question, as indicated by the cities mentioned and the President Luthor bit, so I guess, only American towns/cities.

Comment: @Politank-Z BAD things happen to any Detroit :(

Comment: @BMWurm Most are spared full scale inter-dimensional Borg knockoff invasions, however.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Blüdhaven had a worse crime rate than Gotham.

Comment: @DavidBanner That's just it, I've heard that too - *and* the converse - but noone seems to actually have any numbers for either... :)

Comment: Blüdhaven would probably have a higher crime rate if everyone wasn't [dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bl%C3%BCdhaven#Destruction_of_the_city)

Comment: @Richard Well 100k+ counts of murder could technically still count...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Smallville: Season 11 - Guardian #09](http://smallville.wikia.com/wiki/Smallville_Season_11_Issue_3), **Star City** has the *second* highest crime rate in the US, with Gotham a clear and firm leader as the highest.

[image]